# Debian 9 - Samba - smbpasswd: error while loading shared libraries: liberrors.so.0:

Tags: samba, samba4

I am trying to set up Samba on my Debian 9 server and using `smbpasswd` to set the samba user password. Unfortunately, whenever I run the command:

```
smbpasswd -a myUsersNameHere
```

I get the error

> smbpasswd: error while loading shared libraries: liberrors.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Does anybody know what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `samba-libs` package.

```
apt-get install samba-libs
```

That provides that and other libraries for samba. It looks like you already have the other necessary packages for `samba` or else you'd get a `command not found` error when using `smbpasswd`.

Comment: I already had the package installed, and it still doesn't work after I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs`

Comment: I don't know what part of what I did fixed it, but I ran `sudo apt-get remove samba-libs`, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then `sudo apt-get install samba-libs`, then when I ran `sudo smbpasswd stuart` I got a command not found message, and found I had to run `sudo apt-get install samba` again. Now `sudo smbpasswd stuart` works just fine. Wierd.

Comment: @Programster What that means is that the package had become corrupted in some way which caused the library file(s) to not be found. Something must have then occurred to ruin the `samba` package which caused `smbpasswd` to not be found. I should have asked whether or not you had it installed first but as it's been resolved, I've leave this and your comment here.